# cannot open source file "d3dx9.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I've been having problems with this for months, I've looked at many pages and still couldn't fix it.
I'm on windows 10, using Visual Studio 2019, I've added this to include directories -> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include`, and this to my library directories `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86`. I've also tried adding this to my include and library directories -> `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include`, `$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86`.
[image]

Comment: What does your *code* look like that is failing? What is the actual *error message*?

Answer (score 1):

Your paltform is x64, but your settings `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86 and`  are x86. So, I suggest that you should make sure that these two settings are consistent.

[image]

Comment: @JeduMiSePalacinke Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.